# SMIL: t:audio issue in internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, smil, polyglot, urn, processing-instruction

I am trying to reanimate project made ten years ago. SMIL2 was successfully used in IE6.

I have found that IE8 still supports SMIL, however nor t:media, nor t:audio elements do not play audio/media content any more.

Here is simple example that works OK in IE6 (under VirtualPC) but has issues in IE8

<html xmlns:t="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:time">
<head>
<?import namespace="t" implementation="#default#time2">
</head>
<body>
   <t:audio src="LoopyMusic.wav" repeatCount="indefinite" type="wav" />
</body>
</html>

Another notice - in case if t:audio is included into sequence (t:seq) - element after t:audio never starts it's effects.

Are there any known issues/workarounds with SMIL support under internet explorer 8?

Answer (score 1):

Use a closing tag instead of an empty tag and add the `timecontainer` attribute, since IE8 enforces [stricter syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533595#CommunityContent):

```
<t:audio src="LoopyMusic.wav" repeatCount="indefinite" type="wav" timecontainer="par"></t:audio>
```

**References**

- [Stu Nicholls | CSS PLAY | Internet Explorer Time Action Galleries](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/ie/time-action.html)
- [HTML+TIME: Time Containers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533104(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using the TIMEACTION Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533120(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using HTML+TIME Transitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533792(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Using the HTML+TIME Document Object Model (DOM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533123(v=vs.85).aspx)